# iOS 8.1 Iphone 6 Mail Client can't open links using Chrome

Tags: email, ios

The default mail client can't seem to open email links using chrome at all. I have deactivated safari.  Is this  a glitch? Should I stop using the default client?

Thanks.

Comment: How could you deactivate Safari ???

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Parental Controls

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't choose a default browser other than Safari (without a Jailbreak) it is the normal behaviour.

Comment: Isn't that horrible behaviour?  It opens up links only in Safari?

Comment: @Marin Yes there is no way to change the system-wide browser on iOS currently.